# Read data from text file

Tags: java, java-me

I want to read a few names that are saved in a text file and display it as a radio buttons. How should I go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: does the file contains name in comma separated values.(ex: john,Doe)

Comment: See this [link](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001266_-_Using_List_in_Java_ME) for using Radiobutton in j2me. And also see this [link](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001006_-_Reading_a_text_file_line_by_line) for reading a text file line by line.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand parsing a txt file using String methods. Then initialising a hashtable to get the parsed values.